# Jquery spinning track with items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I founded some nice spinning track on web and everything works perfectly but only question is how to get selected card data-id?
I tried a lot of solutions and searched I couldn't get this worked because I can't define the selected card cuz after the spin I want to search database and get informations for this card.

```js
var $cardList = $('.cardList').first(),
  $cards = $('.card'),
  width = 100,
  randomize = true,
  distance = 20 * width;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  $cards.clone().appendTo($cardList);
}

function spin() {

  var newMargin = 0,
    newDistance = distance,
    speed = 5000;
  if (randomize) {
    newDistance = Math.floor(Math.random() * $cards.length * 5);
    newDistance += $cards.length * 5;
    newDistance *= width;
  }
  newMargin = -(newDistance);
  $cards.first().animate({
    marginLeft: newMargin
  }, speed);

}

$('#spin').click(function() {
  $cards.first().css('margin-left', 0);
  spin();
  return false;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cardList {
  height: 100px;
  width: 302px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #33e;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #99e;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #33e;
  border-right: 1px solid #33e;
}

.cardList::before,
.cardList::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
}

.cardList::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border-top: 12px solid #33e;
}

.cardList::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #33e;
}

div.controls,
button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

div.controls input {
  width: 48px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cardList">
  <div class="card" data-id="1">1</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="2">2</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="3">3</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="4">4</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="5">5</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="6">6</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="7">7</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="8">8</div>

</div>
<button id="spin">Spin</button>
```

Comment: This simple moves the items. I do not see anything that indicates the "selected" card. No class is added to the any specific card. You're looking to add that feature?

Comment: Yes, i cant fiqure how to get spin result (data-id)

Comment: I do not see a way to do that with this specific code. It created clones of the cards, and so you may end up with 400+ cards, with no way to properly select one unique card. I suspect it needs to rotate just the cards in place and adding class as you iterate. Are you looking for random selection?

Comment: Ye that is it , just display some div and on button click rotate whole line and get selected nothing more than that

Comment: what does "selected" mean? usually it means when a user clicks/selects an item. After spinning it stops at a random number. are you calling that number being selected? or the user is supposed to click on it?

Comment: Yes result of a spin is a selected number i didnt mean on clicking numbers or something.. Just spin a track and a random number where spin ends is a selected one if u understand..

Answer (score 1):

You can know the answer before the spinner even starts. This seems to be working so far without any failed guesses.

`var numCardsPassed = newDistance / 100;`
Here I take the generated distance and divide it by the width of a card to get how many cards will shuffle by.

`var answer = Math.floor(STARTING_INDEX + (numCardsPassed % $cards.length));`
Here I figure out which card it will land on after going through the 8 card rotation `numCardsPassed` times (starting at index/card 2).

The cool thing about this approach is you can fetch the data from the database while the cards are shuffling, which will mean you can show the data the instant the animation is done.

```js
// the card the arrows start on, in this case, card 2
const STARTING_INDEX = 2;

var $cardList = $('.cardList').first(),
  $cards = $('.card'),
  width = 100,
  randomize = true,
  distance = 20 * width;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  $cards.clone().appendTo($cardList);
}

function spin() {

  var newMargin = 0,
    newDistance = distance,
    speed = 5000;
  if (randomize) {
    newDistance = Math.floor(Math.random() * $cards.length * 5);
    newDistance += $cards.length * 5;
    newDistance *= width;
  }

  var numCardsPassed = newDistance / 100;
  var answer = Math.floor(STARTING_INDEX + (numCardsPassed % $cards.length));
  console.log("Answer: " + answer);
  newMargin = -(newDistance);
  $cards.first().animate({
    marginLeft: newMargin
  }, speed, function() {
    console.log("animation is done");
  });

}

$('#spin').click(function() {
  $cards.first().css('margin-left', 0);
  spin();
  return false;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cardList {
  height: 100px;
  width: 302px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #33e;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #99e;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #33e;
  border-right: 1px solid #33e;
}

.cardList::before,
.cardList::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
}

.cardList::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border-top: 12px solid #33e;
}

.cardList::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #33e;
}

div.controls,
button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

div.controls input {
  width: 48px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cardList">
  <div class="card" data-id="1">1</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="2">2</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="3">3</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="4">4</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="5">5</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="6">6</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="7">7</div>
  <div class="card" data-id="8">8</div>

</div>
<button id="spin">Spin</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much this is very good , just one more question after more spins he always start from same number roll is there solution to set to roll from previous selected number?

Comment: Sorry one more question is this posibble to get the selected number data id?

Comment: yes you can make an ID on each card that corresponds with the number of the card. Then you can use getElementByID and getAttribute to get the data-id value of the answer. Also, there is definitely a way to set the roll to start at the previous number.